# SQL Cluster IP should this be the same as the WFC cluster IP?

Tags: sql-server, clustering

Been building my first SQL Server cluster.

One question I have: Should the SQL Cluster IP address be the same as the WFC cluster IP address?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No you will need separate IP for Windows Server Failover Cluster (WSFC) and Failover Cluster Instance (FCI, what you mentioned as SQL Cluster).